# Google engine compute image storage vs. snapshot storage - price difference

Tags: image, google-cloud-storage, snapshot

I am looking at [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing) and it looks like snapshot storage is only $0.026 GB/month, while image storage is $0.085. I am curious why there is such a significant difference in storage prices?

Update: Even more interesting fact: standard provisioned space is only $0.04, cheaper than image storage? Why?